# RAILS command line ls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I found method in Rails `ls`.

```
 pry(#<SettingsController>)> ls
ActiveSupport::ToJsonWithActiveSupportEncoder#methods: to_json
ActiveSupport::Configurable#methods: config
AbstractController::Base#methods: action_methods  action_name  action_name=  available_action?  controller_path  response_body
ActionController::Metal#methods: 
  content_type   controller_name  headers   location=         middleware_stack=  performed?  request=       response   response_body=  session       set_response!  status=
  content_type=  dispatch         location  middleware_stack  middleware_stack?  request     reset_session  response=  response_code   set_request!  status         to_a   
#<Module:0x0000000551b030>#methods: env
```

..... and so on

So what does it mean? Is it show us all available methods in the project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `pry` README: https://github.com/pry/pry

> Pry allows us to pop in and out of different scopes (objects) using the cd command. This enables us to explore the run-time view of a program or library. To view which variables and methods are available within a particular scope we use the versatile ls [command](https://gist.github.com/banister/c0fc686ef923c8b87715).